# Startup Items keep getting reset after a period of time?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login-items

On my MacBook running OS X Lion 10.7.4, after a few days the startup items automatically get removed. I find this really annoying, as then I have to add them all back again.

What are the possible causes of this?

Comment: WHere did you put the Startup Items?

Comment: @Mark just in the login items panel in system preferences.